# Rails API: how translate json request in spanish if my model is in english?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Model convention parameters need to be in English, but the input JSON request keys need to send it in Spanish, how is the best practice for rails to accept parameters in Spanish and save in database?

MODEL:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :level, :goals, :salary, :bonus, :team, presence: true
end
```

INPUT:

```
{
   "jugadores" : [  
      {  
         "nombre":"Snow",
         "nivel":"C",
         "goles":10,
         "sueldo":50000,
         "bono":25000,
         "sueldo_completo":null,
         "equipo":"rojo"
      },
      {  
         "nombre":"JC",
         "nivel":"A",
         "goles":30,
         "sueldo":100000,
         "bono":30000,
         "sueldo_completo":null,
         "equipo":"azul"
      }
   ]
}
```

Controller:

```
...
  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)

    if @player.save
      render json: @player, status: :created, location: @player
    else
      render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
...

    def player_params
      params.permit( jugadores: [ :nombre, :nivel, :goles, :salario, :bono, :salario_completo, :equipo ] )
    end
...
```

thnx

Ill tried to translate with I18n, but I can't solve translate ActiveController

$"translation missing: en.{"jugadores"=>{"name"=>"Irving"}}"

Comment: Why does the API need to accept attributes in Spanish when the application with internally written in English? Why don't you require the client (frontend or API user) to send the request in the correct language? And what about other languages, do you need to accept request with Portuguese or French attributes too? And what about the response do you need to translate attribute names in responses?

Comment: Lets say for the sake of the example that you have a bad client out there in the wild and **really** had to accept spanish parameters. In that case I would setup an Adapter class that takes the garbage input and normalizes it for your application. This can be just a Plain Old Ruby Object that takes the parameters as input and returns a new parameters object with the correct keys. You want to keep the crazy contained as much as possible so that it becomes less painful later when you can deprechiate the nonsense.

Comment: max yeah and spickermann, thnx for take a time to reply, it's only an exercise, I realized this is a bad implementation, outside the conventions. btw, i solved it iterating the ActionController and translating keys with I18n, at the same time.
But, I don't know if this affects the performance of my api. Haha, it's garbage, take care